# How to obtain the "provider specific schema" for an access.mdb?

Tags: vba, ms-access

How do I identify the "provider specific schema" for an MS-Access database please?

The schema example below:

```
{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}
```

Comment: Googling `provider specific schema` gives on first page http://allenbrowne.com/func-ado.html .  You ought to try some of this code for yourself and then post a better question.  You should provide evidence of research.

Comment: I have googled this and found several posts stating what it can be used for but nothing clearly stating how to get the number. Some context on how to achieve the number would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Googling for `{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}` turns up this page http://allenbrowne.com/func-ado.html.  An example usage is found on that page (but is in fact copied from https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/198755)

```
Option Explicit

Function ShowUserRosterMultipleUsers()
    'Source: kb 198755.
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    'Dim cn2 As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i, j As Long

    cn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    cn.Open "Data Source=C:\Data\Northwind2003.mdb"

    'cn2.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=C:\Data\Northwind2003.mdb"

    ' The user roster is exposed as a provider-specific schema rowset
    ' in the Jet 4 OLE DB provider.  You have to use a GUID to
    ' reference the schema, as provider-specific schemas are not
    ' listed in ADO's type library for schema rowsets

    Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaProviderSpecific, , "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}")

    'Output the list of all users in the current database.

    Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Name, "", rs.Fields(1).Name, "", rs.Fields(2).Name, rs.Fields(3).Name

    While Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(0), rs.Fields(1), rs.Fields(2), rs.Fields(3)
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
End Function
```

Investigating the OpenSchema method gives two links 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676705(v=vs.85).aspx | 
http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_conn_openschema.asp
The second of these links seems to indicate that one can open a great variety of schemas but if a provider specific schema is required then one must pass `adSchemaProviderSpecific` and then the GUI.  In the Microsoft link above it says

> "The GUID for a provider-schema query not defined by the OLE DB specification."

So where does this schemaid `{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}` number come?  In my opinion it comes from the developers of the Jet Database Engine OLE DB Provider.

What is interesting is that your question implie there is one guid per database (.mdb file).  In fact I believe it to be at the OLE DB provider, so I think your question is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

As a result of my search for Google Books, it appears in Programmers' Refferbce. This GUID is JET_SCHEMA_USERROSTER.
[Access 2003 Programmers' Reference page 208](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=pyNXDb_VmcAC&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=%22%7B947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675%7D%22&source=bl&ots=KzjA1h18-k&sig=ACfU3U0UZo8yTe4ui2fXYM2hrLtZNzS57w&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjow4HLxMLkAhXNMd4KHU2SDhs4ChDoATADegQIChAB#v=onepage&q=%22%7B947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675%7D%22&f=false)

JET Proviser Provides 8 Provider-Specific-Schema Recordset.

On the Internet, it was previously published here in Japanese.
https://www.microsoft.com/japan/msdn/data/techmat/ado/dao2ado_11.asp

```
' Security GUIDS for Access Objects
Global Const JET_SECURITY_FORMS = "{c49c842e-9dcb-11d1-9f0a-00c04fc2c2e0}"
Global Const JET_SECURITY_REPORTS = "{c49c8430-9dcb-11d1-9f0a-00c04fc2c2e0}"
Global Const JET_SECURITY_MACROS = "{c49c842f-9dcb-11d1-9f0a-00c04fc2c2e0}"
Global Const JET_SECURITY_MODULES = "{c49c8432-9dcb-11d1-9f0a-00c04fc2c2e0}"
' Jet OLE DB Provider Defined Schema Rowsets
Global Const JET_SCHEMA_REPLPARTIALFILTERLIST = "{e2082df0-54ac-11d1-bdbb-00c04fb92675}"
Global Const JET_SCHEMA_REPLCONFLICTTAGBLES = "{e2082df2-54ac-11d1-bdbb-00c04fb92675}"
Global Const JET_SCHEMA_USERROSTER = "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}"`
Global Const JET_SCHEMA_ISAMSTATS = "{8703b612-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}" `
```